# Bluetooth Programming using the "Blue Pill" or stm32f103c8

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, uart

I am presented an issue in context of utilising Bluetooth with my blue pill. This is an external HC-05 chip ( slave only ) When connecting via. my Android phone I am able to successfully connect but am expecting to see a welcome message ( see code ), currently no data is being sent and I believe it's from my new-ness to embedded development and the ARM family.

I have been able to successfully blink a LED at different intervals of my choosing; leveraging the StmCubeMX application that sets all my peripherals up for me. I have tried to do the same thing using the UART by following tutorials all the pins are connected properly to the mapped UART1 pin i'm using. I have tried debugging in Atollic without luck due to some application issues.

To summarise elegantly - I want to send a "hello world" type of message when the Android phone connects and eventually a receive event, high level essentially I am using the bluetooth as a way to control the bluepill and perform X action like blink a light.

**usart.c FILE**

```
#include "usart.h"


UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USART1 init function */

void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(uartHandle->Instance==USART1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 0 */
    /* USART1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA9     ------> USART1_TX
    PA10     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_UART_MspDeInit(UART_HandleTypeDef* uartHandle)
{

  if(uartHandle->Instance==USART1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
    PA9     ------> USART1_TX
    PA10     ------> USART1_RX 
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10);
  }
} 






int main(void)
{

/* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  char message [30] = "hey I am connected to you";
  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
        HAL_Delay(200);
        // HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, message, sizeof(message), 1000);
    HAL_Delay(1000);
  }
}
```

**ACTUAL:** LED blinks but no string is sent to the Android Phone

**EXPECTED:** When I open up the blueterm application I should see the message sent from the board upon successful connection

Comment: What happens when you check the UART1 output and when you send something from the PC to the STM.

Comment: There is nothing there in both cases ( send or receive ) I had a gap in my knowledge in context of the baud rate I guess the HC-05 functions at 38400 I need to set it to this and hopefully I see something - I will update the post after, thanks.

Comment: So I made a mistake actually this is the HC-06 module not the HC-05 Baud rate is 9600 by default apparently, so this code would be the same code I am stuck on.